# Starting JBoss from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss

Staring JBoss server from within Eclipse Ganymede gives me the following problem:
"Server JBoss v4.0 at localhost was unable to start within 120 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."

The console shows JBoss has started in so and so minutes but soon after, there is a pop up if the above message.
I can also start the JBoss externally.

Comment: The other comments are right, JUST DOUBLE CLICK SERVER in the SERVER VIEW....

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem, but it was with a Tomcat 5.5 server.
The startup time was quite important, so I got this error.

To solve this problem, I did that steps:
In Preferences, Server, I changed the property "Server timeout delay" to "Unlimited".

**Edit:**

For Eclipse Ganymede, you must do that:
In the server view, double-click on your server JBoss.
In the overview, you have a "Timeouts" panel (by default, it is collapsed).
You can define the timeouts for server start and stop operations.

Comment: Well...I have tried doing that already...increasing the server timeout from 50 sec to 2 min made no difference...

BTW...could it be a problem that I use jdk 1.5 with JBoss 4.0.1

Comment: That double click is extremely well hidden :(

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem. It turned out that Eclipse’s server default port was set to `8080` while my JBoss was working from `8180`.

By changing the server’s configuration in Eclipse (double-click on the server and edit server property), it worked.

Comment: I had the same issue and this was the resolution for me. When I created a new JBoss server within Ecilpse, it asked me what Port to use, so I chose 8081. However, that doesn't actually affect what Port JBoss will start on, JBoss still starts on 8080. So, it was checking for the server to start on 8081 which never happened, but JBoss did actually successfully start on 8080. Silly mistake.

Comment: same here: for me the problem was that port 8080 was entered in config, but it was actually running on port 80

Comment: The reason that changing to 8080 works that not because 8080 is the port number we should use(but it is always the default one). We need to check server.xml file and see what is set there for serving the project and then set corresponded port number in your jboss  in eclipse.

Answer (score 13):

Increasing the timeout doesn't solve the problem. Eclipse never recognizes that the server has started (not sure if that's a big deal), just irritated me. I had this problem for weeks and finally figured out that (at least for me) the host name and address had to be identical. I had hostname:localhost; address"127.0.0.1" and it would not work. I changed both to 127.0.0.1 and voila!

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my Eclipse with Jboss Tools, that ocurred too, I change the "Host name", on General information of JbossServer, from my machine name to 127.0.0.1.

Thanks, this works fine!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behavior when I've changed JBoss to run via SSL on port 8443 instead of unencrypted on port 8080.  It is my theory that the Eclipse plugin is checking on port 8080 to confirm that JBoss has started, and that this check is hardcoded and does not respect changes you make to the configuration to specify that the server runs on a different port.

Our workaround is to start JBoss from the debug pulldown menu, which apparently disables the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change ports defined in JBoss configuration panel. I have used -`Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01` to upgrade port numbers - and forgot to change Eclipse/JBoss configuration - and Eclipse failed to notice JBoss is already running.

Comment: Me too. I had to set the same port in "Server Ports".

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:-

1. Check if the port jboss configured correctly in the general information. It is usually 8080 unless you've changed it.
2. I use the hostname as 0.0.0.0 so that it can be accessed from other computers on the network.
3. I had a problem where I was connected to a vpn and it was causing this issue. Shut off any vpn connections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had similar problem Jboss could not start from Eclipse Galileo within default 50 secs
so just changed server startup time by double clicking Jboss server icon in Server window near console & error log (NOT at windows->preferences->server). It opens server editor and then increased the start up time to 300
It worked then. !!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and corrected it by modifying a "server.xml" file in the jboss folders.

```
I modified  '<Connector port="8080"' by '<Connector port="server port defined in Eclipse"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check whether you are running Jboss version 4.0.4 or version 4.2.2.  You might get this error when you have installed Jboss 4.2.2 but configured Jboss 4.0.4 in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the jBoss server icon in the server view. A window pops up with “Timeout” collapsed. Click on the arrow and increase the start time.

Answer (score 0):

Are yoy runing on Linux?
If so, check if jBoss has write privileges over /tmp ...

I had the same problem, and I fixed creating a temp directory with RW privileges to User, Group and others, and adding this line to eclipse.ini

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=yourTempDirectory
```

where your temp directory is the absolute addres of the Temp directory that you created.

Answer (score 0):

I've come upon the same problem and found the explanation. For Eclipse, JBoss is expected to support the jboss-web service (tomcat.sar) which implies an HTTP port to be opened at the end of the process. In my case, as this service is disabled, no HTTP port is opened when the server is running...

Solution: simply double click on the jboss server in the Servers panel and copy the JNDI port to the Port field, in Server Properties section. This makes it.

This way, it is no more necessary to change host name to 127.0.0.1, you may let it be what you want (e.g. localhost is the default).

Answer (score 0):

I am new to EJB - Jboss. I too was getting the same problem

> Jboss Is not started in given time,  increase Start-up time out]]

It is not solved by your given valuable suggestions.

According to console: My Jboss-5.1.0.GA Server started in 50:21, 49:91 ...so on.

But not responded well with given host name: `10.168.2.11`
Server Configuration Server: 10.168.2.11 which I like to execute when using ant.

Solution: All though It is worked well with

```
host Name: localhost
Server Name:localhost
```

Even increased port i.e. ports-02: result in http: port 8280

---

Attempted every practice given here. This is mine. Hope that eclipse community with jboss collaboration give right solution.

I don't know but bit Ground point in this Suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/945444/1164686

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "JBoss 4.2 at localhost" at "servers" window and select open, after that,
just change the port number from 8080 to 8081 and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix it by using Aboucabar Toure's advice: under Eclipse Indigo, I opened JBoss server properties and edited the Server Ports group to match my JBoss ports configuration (unchecking Detect from Local Runtime boxes).

Then everything worked just fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a non default port for, instance 8180. You should configure eclipse to poll server at desired port number. See this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This also happened when you create the jboss with different server version. I was using JBoss AS 7.2.0 final but had no idea to use which server version in eclipse. I tried with WildFly but that leads to this error. With all the good tips in here didn't solve my problem. Thanks to this [post](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToCreateconfigurestartstopJBossAS720RuntimeServerWithEclipseIDE43keplerjbosstools41-EnglishVersion) i corrected that with correct version. I should have used Jboss Enterprise Application platform 6.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove all eclipse breakpoint in the debug view, and the jboss will quickly start.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue, after change the port number it has worked for me.

Port number in server.xml and jboss port number should be same.

goto -> jboss-4.0.3\server\default\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat55.sar\server.xml

Connector port="9090"

goto -> Double click on server and change your port number as what you gave in server.xml