# Jboss 4.2 not starting on win 7 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, application-server, jboss-4.2.x

I have JBoss-4.2.3.GA,
Which is unable to start in a given time even if I increase the start time and stop time  to 500 Seconds.

I later tried with other versions of JBOSS 4.2 but it is not starting either.

Long back (In some other system) i was getting similar problem in windows 7 64 bit, for which i changed XX:MaxPermSize  which solved the issue. But it is not helping here.

I am using eclipse indigo 
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
to start the server.

The console after starting the server says:

```
13:05:08,325 INFO  [Server] Starting JBoss (MX MicroKernel)...
13:05:08,325 INFO  [Server] Release ID: JBoss [Trinity] 4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)
13:05:08,327 INFO  [Server] Home Dir: C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA
13:05:08,327 INFO  [Server] Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/
13:05:08,327 INFO  [Server] Patch URL: null
13:05:08,327 INFO  [Server] Server Name: default
13:05:08,328 INFO  [Server] Server Home Dir: C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default
13:05:08,328 INFO  [Server] Server Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/
13:05:08,328 INFO  [Server] Server Log Dir: C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\log
13:05:08,328 INFO  [Server] Server Temp Dir: C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\default\tmp
13:05:08,328 INFO  [Server] Root Deployment Filename: jboss-service.xml
13:05:08,492 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_35,Sun Microsystems Inc.
13:05:08,492 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.10-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc.
13:05:08,493 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
13:05:08,728 INFO  [Server] Core system initialized
13:05:09,745 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
13:05:09,746 INFO  [Log4jService$URLWatchTimerTask] Configuring from URL: resource:jboss-log4j.xml
13:05:09,969 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.
13:05:09,969 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
13:05:10,077 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting recovery manager
13:05:10,117 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager started
13:05:10,117 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
13:05:11,387 INFO  [EJB3Deployer] Starting java:comp multiplexer
13:05:12,542 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Native
13:05:12,542 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] jbossws-3.0.1-native-2.0.4.GA (build=200803312044)
13:05:13,070 INFO  [Embedded] Catalina naming disabled
13:05:13,149 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;.
13:05:13,182 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
13:05:13,183 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
13:05:13,183 INFO  [Catalina] Initialization processed in 113 ms
13:05:13,183 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web
13:05:13,185 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA
13:05:13,215 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 31 ms
13:05:13,280 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/, warUrl=.../deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war/
13:05:13,602 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker, warUrl=.../deploy/http-invoker.sar/invoker.war/
13:05:13,714 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws, warUrl=.../deploy/jbossws.sar/jbossws-context.war/
13:05:13,819 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossmq-httpil, warUrl=.../deploy/jms/jbossmq-httpil.sar/jbossmq-httpil.war/
13:05:14,231 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console, warUrl=.../deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/
13:05:14,510 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
13:05:14,589 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-local-jdbc.rar
13:05:14,607 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-xa-jdbc.rar
13:05:14,625 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar
13:05:14,642 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar
13:05:14,673 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms/jms-ra.rar
13:05:14,692 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/mail-ra.rar
13:05:14,722 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/quartz-ra.rar
13:05:14,730 INFO  [QuartzResourceAdapter] start quartz!!!
13:05:14,768 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
13:05:14,784 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
13:05:14,785 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
13:05:14,785 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
13:05:14,785 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
13:05:14,785 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
13:05:15,309 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
13:05:15,444 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A
13:05:15,445 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B
13:05:15,446 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C
13:05:15,447 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D
13:05:15,448 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex
13:05:15,457 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic
13:05:15,458 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic
13:05:15,459 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic
13:05:15,461 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue
13:05:15,479 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : /127.0.0.1:8093
13:05:15,494 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ
13:05:15,549 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
13:05:15,567 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console, warUrl=.../deploy/jmx-console.war/
13:05:15,688 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
13:05:15,706 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
13:05:15,717 INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)] Started in 7s:388ms
```

It says started but it is not completely starting.

My server overview is as follows:

[image: Server Configurations]

I am getting same error as below for 500 seconds, but I am attaching a snapshot for 10 seconds.

[image: Eclipse Message]

I am attaching contents of run.bat, run.conf  files in bin folder of Jboss :

**run.bat**

```
@echo off
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem JBoss Bootstrap Script for Win32
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------

rem $Id: run.bat 73584 2008-05-22 12:09:26Z dimitris@jboss.org $

@if not "%ECHO%" == ""  echo %ECHO%
@if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT"  setlocal

set DIRNAME=.\
if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" set DIRNAME=%~dp0%
set PROGNAME=run.bat
if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" set PROGNAME=%~nx0%

pushd %DIRNAME%..
set JBOSS_HOME=%CD%
popd

REM Add bin/native to the PATH if present
if exist "%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\native" set PATH=%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\native;%PATH%
if exist "%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\native" set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path="%PATH%"

rem Find run.jar, or we can't continue

set RUNJAR=%JBOSS_HOME%\bin\run.jar
if exist "%RUNJAR%" goto FOUND_RUN_JAR
echo Could not locate %RUNJAR%. Please check that you are in the
echo bin directory when running this script.
goto END

:FOUND_RUN_JAR

if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto ADD_TOOLS

set JAVA=java

echo JAVA_HOME is not set.  Unexpected results may occur.
echo Set JAVA_HOME to the directory of your local JDK to avoid this message.
goto SKIP_TOOLS

:ADD_TOOLS

set JAVA=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java

rem A full JDK with toos.jar is not required anymore since jboss web packages
rem the eclipse jdt compiler and javassist has its own internal compiler.
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar" goto SKIP_TOOLS

rem If exists, point to the JDK javac compiler in case the user wants to
rem later override the eclipse jdt compiler for compiling JSP pages.
set JAVAC_JAR=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar

:SKIP_TOOLS

rem If JBOSS_CLASSPATH or JAVAC_JAR is empty, don't include it, as this will 
rem result in including the local directory in the classpath, which makes
rem error tracking harder.
if not "%JAVAC_JAR%" == "" set RUNJAR=%JAVAC_JAR%;%RUNJAR%
if "%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%" == "" set RUN_CLASSPATH=%RUNJAR%
if "%RUN_CLASSPATH%" == "" set RUN_CLASSPATH=%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%;%RUNJAR%

set JBOSS_CLASSPATH=%RUN_CLASSPATH%

rem Setup JBoss specific properties
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dprogram.name=%PROGNAME%

rem Add -server to the JVM options, if supported
"%JAVA%" -server -version 2>&1 | findstr /I hotspot > nul
if not errorlevel == 1 (set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -server)

rem JVM memory allocation pool parameters. Modify as appropriate.
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

rem With Sun JVMs reduce the RMI GCs to once per hour
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000

rem JPDA options. Uncomment and modify as appropriate to enable remote debugging.
rem set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y %JAVA_OPTS%

rem Setup the java endorsed dirs
set JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=%JBOSS_HOME%\lib\endorsed

echo ===============================================================================
echo.
echo   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
echo.
echo   JBOSS_HOME: %JBOSS_HOME%
echo.
echo   JAVA: %JAVA%
echo.
echo   JAVA_OPTS: %JAVA_OPTS%
echo.
echo   CLASSPATH: %JBOSS_CLASSPATH%
echo.
echo ===============================================================================
echo.

:RESTART
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% ^
   -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%" ^
   -classpath "%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%" ^
   org.jboss.Main %*

if ERRORLEVEL 10 goto RESTART

:END
if "%NOPAUSE%" == "" pause

:END_NO_PAUSE
```

**run.conf**

```
## -*- shell-script -*- ######################################################
##                                                                          ##
##  JBoss Bootstrap Script Configuration                                    ##
##                                                                          ##
##############################################################################

### $Id: run.conf 62747 2007-05-02 17:43:36Z dimitris@jboss.org $

#
# This file is optional; it may be removed if not needed.
#

#
# Specify the maximum file descriptor limit, use "max" or "maximum" to use
# the default, as queried by the system.
#
# Defaults to "maximum"
#
#MAX_FD="maximum"

#
# Specify the profiler configuration file to load.
#
# Default is to not load profiler configuration file.
#
#PROFILER=""

#
# Specify the location of the Java home directory.  If set then $JAVA will
# be defined to $JAVA_HOME/bin/java, else $JAVA will be "java".
#
#JAVA_HOME="/opt/java/jdk"

#
# Specify the exact Java VM executable to use.
#
#JAVA=""

#
# Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
fi

# Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debuging
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

# Sample JPDA settings for shared memory debugging 
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,suspend=n,address=jboss"
```

Please help me resolve this issue, so that I can start working on my server.

Comment: Can you explain better? The console output seems ok so there is no way to understand the issue.

Comment: Why do you think it is not completly started?

Comment: @remigio Yes, Even i feel the same...
But it is not started, i hit the url http://localhost:8090 (the port number i have configured) and jboss console is not appearing,
And I get a message in eclipse- 'Starting JBoss V4.2 at localhost' has encountered a problem - JBoss v4.2 at localhost

Comment: Why don't you include the complete output from the JBoss log, is it the message `'Starting JBoss V4.2 at localhost' has encountered a problem - JBoss v4.2 at localhost –` the only error message you get? Unfortunately it's not enough to guess anything

Comment: @remigio i have pasted everything on the console- I have not left a single word,  
If you need any other configurations please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the line in the log:

13:05:13,182 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080.

It states that the http listens to port 8080 (not port 8090), so you should access through the address localhost:8080.

Where have you configured the http port? You shouldn't change directly the ports of the services, instead use JBoss Service binding Set, Take in mind JBoss opens several ports, so to avoid port conflicts you should change them all.

Check: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfiguringMultipleJBossInstancesOnOneMachine

UPDATE: The Eclipse screen you've posted doesn't change the port of the JBoss, it's used by Elcipse to know where Jboss http is listening, so you've not really changed the port in JBoss.

On the other hand, a part from the port problem, if you startup the JBoss server from Eclipse, you've to increase the time Eclipse waits JBoss to get started (if JBoss takes more time than the "[Server timeout delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298312/starting-jboss-from-eclipse)" property of the server in Eclipse, it will return an error).

Comment: it is working on port 8080 as you said.
But after the server start time out (500 seconds in this example) i get a message that cannot start server as said in the snapshot.

Comment: @toni..
Reply for the update: how to change the port in my jboss.
Please guide me.
I dont know how to do it.

Comment: You can find the way to really change the ports of JBoss in the link I've posted, look for the section: "Providing alternate ports for each instance of JBoss AS" there you'll find instructions for JBoss 4.x. If you find any problem, let me know. Basically the Bindings Service Set, allows you to add an offset to all the ports JBoss listen to (instead of just chanding one particular port), this way you can even startup several instances of JBoss in the same machine). If you want http listen to 8090, you'll have to use an offset of 10 (that is 8080 + 10 = 8090).

Comment: But i have only one server installed in my system, and only one server i have configured that is the JBoss V4.2 as mentioned above.

Comment: Even if you've just one server, the bindings system let you change the port numbers, but if you still really want to change just the http port, you can configure it in the file: deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml (mmm, I usually use JBoss5, so maybe in JBoss4 the file server.xml is in the deploy/jbossweb-tomcat or something like that). In this file you've the HTTP Connector, change its port property to 8090 (by default it's set to 8080). But consider using the bindings method :-)

Comment: Entire Problem solved as i altered server.xml

Thanks for the assistance tony.
Thanks a lot